# Does JSON decoding method affect the validity of the token?

Tags: python, rest, dart

For example, there is a JSON object written in Dart and Python

```dart
final jsonData = {'access_key':'i-want-to-authorized','param1': 'parameter1'};
```

```py
jsonData = {'access_key':'i-want-to-authorized','param1': 'parameter1'}
```

and if I stringify these variables like this

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

final jsonData = {'access_key':'i-want-to-be-authorized','param1': 'parameter1'};
final dumpedJson = json.encode(jsonData);

print(dumpedJson);
```

```py
import json

jsonData = {'access_key':'i-want-to-be-authorized','param1': 'parameter1'}
dumped_json = json.dumps(jsonData)

print(dumped_json)
```

When I execute the codes above, I get the following results.

In Dart, `{"access_key":"i-want-to-be-authorized","param1":"parameter1"}`
In Python, `{"access_key": "i-want-to-be-authorized", "param1": "parameter1"}`

As you can see, the JSON library in Python puts space after every colon and comma, which makes the total different result when it's encrypted in anyways.

Though I believe that when they're all decrypted and decoded, they will be taken the same on the server-side but is it probable that this difference makes the server not able to comprehend the request?

Comment: If code depends on the textual format of JSON, it is fundamentally broken (and indeed some usages are broken..). Both representations are valid and represent the same data. It is up to the consumer to correctly treat this as JSON-encoded data instead of “opaque text”. Consider that the ordering of fields is also irrelevant to valid consumers.

Comment: So if the consumers are implemented properly, they don't really matter. I get it. Thank you very much. I just tried some requests with some api and it worked in Python but not in Dart. That's weird but God knows how it's implemented on server-side. Anyway, thank you again.

Comment: Hopefully there is some documentation that specifies the precise JSON *subset* that is required..